# Keras call unable to be called from inside list?

Tags: python, keras

I am currently getting a an error message that I am out of index range for list I am iterating, but that cannot be the case at all.. 
The error seem to appear when i make the call conv1d(input) but these calls are being stored in a list to avoid writing multiple lines of code being copy paste of the same.

Here is the code:

```
    list_of_input = [Input(shape = (window_height,total_frames_with_deltas,3)) for i in range(splits)]
    list_of_convolution = [(Conv1D(filters = J, kernel_size = 8)) for i in range(45)]
    conv_output = []
    for inputs in list_of_input:
        s = Lambda(slice)(inputs)
        for index in xrange(len(list_of_convolution)):
            print len(s)
            print type(s)
            print len(list_of_convolution)
            print type(list_of_convolution)
            print index
            print "At index"
            print s[index]
            print "con"
            print list_of_convolution[index]
            print "Some"
            output = list_of_convolution[index](s[index])
            print "utu"
            conv_output.append(output)
            print len(conv_output)
            raw_input("Soes")
```

And this is the output I am getting with the error message:

```
45
<type 'list'>
45
<type 'list'>
0
At index
Tensor("lambda_1/strided_slice:0", shape=(?, 8, 3), dtype=float32)
con
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv1D object at 0x7fef61fa2a90>
Some
utu
1
Soes
45
<type 'list'>
45
<type 'list'>
1
At index
Tensor("lambda_1/strided_slice_1:0", shape=(?, 8, 3), dtype=float32)
con
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv1D object at 0x7fef61fa2d10>
Some
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_cnn_phoneme_original_fit_generator.py", line 222, in <module>
    fws()
  File "keras_cnn_phoneme_original_fit_generator.py", line 173, in fws
    output = list_of_convolution[index](s[index])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 572, in __call__
    previous_mask = _collect_previous_mask(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2703, in _collect_previous_mask
    mask = node.output_masks[tensor_index]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your index error is coming from inside the call of `list_of_convolution[index](s[index])`, not either of the indexes. Try writing it out in steps:

```
callable = list_of_convolution[index]
arg = s[index]
callable(arg)  # <- this is where the error happens
```

Comment: That cannot be that either..  
It works in the first run, but in the second run it fails. 
Both argument contains the same same and function in both iteration...

Comment: The error is inside the call to `callable` above, not in the indexing (look at the traceback and where it comes from). This means the error is internal to the library (and probably the way you're using it), and not the indexing that your code above shows. I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with Keras, so I won't be much help debugging what you're doing wrong besides telling you that the error is definitely in the call.

Comment: ahh ok.. Well that cleared one thing.. I changed the question btw.